# Domain driven design, best practice. Where should I create my view models

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, architecture, domain-driven-design

In my web application a product is defined by N number of product options and a product object. To display a full product I need to create a view model that will hold the product object, a list of product options and for each product option a list of possible values. My question is what is best practice? Where should I construct this object?

In my mvc application I have a service layer, should I do it in the service layer and have something like productservice.getproduct(id) return the view model ready for the view...or in my controller do I use a combination of...

`Productservice.getProduct(Id) and productoptionService.getProductoptions(productId)`

And then inside the controller construct the view Model?

My guess is to go with the first option, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a bit complicated because what one developer means by a service is something else to another.

So how do we continue?

Well we know it is the responsibility of the Controller to mediate between the View and the ViewModel.

- Mapping from the request to the ViewModel
- Choosing the appropriate View
- And delivering the ViewModel to the View

Keeping in mind that one ViewModel to one View is generally a good practice.

So what about your Domain model?

Well it's best to keep that seperate don't allow it to leak into your controller, this is to prevent any sort of UI specific information from accidentily making its way onto your Domain model.

Personally I practise the following, I have a slim layer (call it a manager or service) that returns a ViewModel, and receives a ViewModel when talking to the controller. But when talking to my internals talks with my Domain model.

So Controller -> Manager -> Service

Manager maps between Domain model and ViewModel.

For example:

```
public class MemberManager 
{
  public MemberService MemberService {get;set;}

  public MemberViewModel GetMember(int id)
  {
      var domainModel = MemberService.GetMember(id);      
      return new MemberViewModel { FullName = domainModel.FullName };
  }

  public bool UpdateMember(MemberViewModel viewModel)
  {
      MemberService.Update(new MemberDomainModel { Id = viewModel.Id, FullName = viewModel.FullName });

     return true; // all good.
  }
}
```

And your controller.

```
public class MemberController 
{
   public MemberManager MemberManager {get;set;}

   public ActionResult View(int id)
   { 
     var viewModel = MemberManager.Get(id);
     return View(viewModel);
   } 
}
```

Comment: I'm not convinced another layer of abstraction is required. Yes I have one view model for one view, the view model is just used to display the Product and all its options to the user, I was thinking if the service returns the already constructed view model, it could be reused for a mobile site for example?

SO I do agree with you, actually but I don't think that the member manager bit is actually needed.

Comment: nope. consider this your mobile site might require different things on its viewmodel, mobile specific controls or data? what if you consume your service from a forms app, what will that required? or create an API that requires JSON? in these cases now your service returns the wrong kind of entity, a viewmodel specific to html, and it will take a lot of refactoring to make it neutral again, and ready for re-use. It seems like more work, and it is, but you are keeping the context of what it does specific, seperate and to only one responsibility.

Comment: @sheku Your right :-) I guess I could call the services to return just the raw entities and construct the view model in the controller. It now makes perfect sense, but I still don't think in my particular scenario I need a 'Manager' layer but I can see in some others where this could be useful

Comment: Yup you can do that too. :D

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding of DDD and MVC's view-model, the one you mentioned return from `productservice.getproduct(id)` is belong to domain model and the view model is just used for
pass data to view for display purpose. So in my opinion, you should have a view-model which is a combination of `Productservice.getProduct(Id), productoptionService.getProductoptions(productId)`
and you should construct your view-model in your controller by calling these 2 methods.

Comment: The only thing is I was thinking that if I do it by using a combination of the two in my controller if I want to do the same thing some where else in the application I will have to repeat the logic of constructing the view model.

Comment: @user2537315. In this case, if you have something need to be consumed across the application, you can just make it as 1. common method in the utility class 2. (I perfer) part of you domain model behaviors